# Where a mistake in the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Here we have a controller:

```
public class CollegeController : Controller
{
    private ICollegeRepository repository;
    public int pageSize = 10;
    public CollegeController(ICollegeRepository repo)
    {
        repository = repo;
    }

    public ViewResult List(string region,
                           string area,
                           string localityType, int page = 1)
    {
        CollegeListViewModel model = new CollegeListViewModel
        {
            Colleges = repository.Colleges
            .Where(p => (region == null || p.Area.Region.Name == region)
            && (localityType == null || p.LocalityType.Name == localityType))
            .Where(p => area == null || p.Area.Name == area)
            .OrderBy(college => college.CollegeId)
            .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage  = page,
                ItemsPerPage = pageSize,
                TotalItems   = ((region == null) && (localityType == null)) ?
            repository.Colleges.Count() :
            repository.Colleges.Where(college => college.Area.Region.Name == region)
                               .Where(college => college.Area.Name == area)
                               .Where(college => college.LocalityType.Name == localityType).Count()
            },
            CurrentLocalityType = localityType,
            CurrentRegion = region,
            CurrentArea = area,
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

The whole problem is that when you start if you pass the first region, and then localityType, everything is fine.

But if you try to pass localityType, when in the region passed null, localityType also sends null.

In other words, before sending localityType must pass region

How such to correct?

And Sorry for my English

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but you need to update the Where clauses within PagingInfo to check for null parameters as you have for the earlier Where clauses - it's possible this is preventing your results from being displayed as TotalCount will end up as 0 if you specify a localityType with a null region.

Comment: @Ben Jackson same, no changes(

Comment: Have you tried passing a ternary into the where clause? Ive had to do that on many occasions after linq doesnt translate the local conditions correctly. Specifically in how SQL infers the OR clause.

Comment: @Botonomous can you give an example. please? cause my English is pretty poor and I am not sure, that I understand you correctly

Comment: repository.Colleges.Where( Region == null && localityType == null ? p.Area.Region.Name == region && p.LocalityType.Name == localityType : true)

Chain the rest of the where clauses with this same format. Try that